# Swift - App Tracking Transparency - How to show non-personalised AdMob content?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I'm trying to implement the App Tracking Transparency framework, and I'm stuck, how do I load non-personalised content when the user denies the prompt.

```
    if #available(iOS 14.5, *) {
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { (status) in
            switch status {
            case .denied:
                // What do I do here?
                //GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
            case .restricted, .notDetermined, .authorized:
                GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
            @unknown default: break
            }
        }
    } else {
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to do anything different.  If the user denies tracking then the ad framework will simply receive 0000 for the IDFA.  This prevents them from identifying the user and tracking them or providing personalised ads.

```
if #available(iOS 14.5, *) {
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { (status) in
            ADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
        }
    } else {
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

You could use the `.denied` status to show an alert that asks them to go into settings and allow it, but don't do that.

Comment: What if you don't want to request tracking at all and always default to not using app tracking. Is this possible?

Comment: Then don't include any code that uses the IDFA in your app. If you do then Apple will detect it and ask at review time why your app doesn't ask for tracking permission.  They might be OK if you just tell them you don't actually use the IDFA value. Certainly you will get 0's if you attempt to read it without asking permission.

Comment: Yea this is the issue I'm running into because the Mobile Ads Sdk references IDFA under the hood. Essentially, I believe the only way to do this would be find an sdk with a "strict" version similar to the one Firebase Analytics released that does not reference IDFA.

Comment: Also, when I use the implementation described the app crashes whenever I change the tracking preference in settings. Is there a way to force reload the app if a change in the preference is detected?

Comment: It shouldn't crash. What is the crash.

Comment: If you go to settings, change the tracking preference for the app, then return to the app it quits (signal 9). You could of course just relaunch the app but nonetheless I would like to avoid crashes. (I'm calling the .start() in didFinishLaunching is this the right place or is there somewhere better?)

Comment: Are you running under Xcode at this point?  There are some preference changes that will result in iOS terminating and relaunching your app. This is probably one of those. If you are running under Xcode then iOS will not relaunch your app for you. Try running the app directly in the device and changing the setting

Comment: Yep this was the issue. Running on device as expected. Thanks!